# OpenGL ES - where to find great resources

Tags: documentation, ios, opengl-es

As the title describes - I am looking for some good OpenGL ES resources.  A lot of what I am seeing is beyond the level of startup...  Looking for some good resources that build your knowledge up - starting off simple and working up to complex topics.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning OpenGL ES 1.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72288/learning-opengl-es-1-x)

Comment: See also [Books on OpenGL ES targeted towards the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081293/books-on-opengl-es-targeted-towards-the-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good luck with that... OpenGL documentation is downright comical. I have used GL ES in 3 Android projects so far, and while it's quite easy once you've got the hang of it, I can't recommend any particular online source.

I invested in the [OpenGL Superbible](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/), worked through the first 4 chapters or so, and then knew enough about projections and textures etc to pick up what I needed pretty quickly.